# rails redirect_to custom view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I'm trying to redirect to a custom view from a controller in my rails app. The following works:

```
redirect_to :action => 'myaction', :id =>@myobj.id
```

An I have a controller action named `myaction`

In my routes.rb file I have

```
match 'myobjs/:id/myaction' => 'myobjs#myaction'
```

But I would like to use the more concise syntax of

```
// this is the line I cannot get to work
redirect_to myaction_path
```

What is the correct syntax for redirecting to a custom view like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `:as` option you can pass to the `match` method.

```
match 'myobjs/:id/myaction' => 'myobjs#myaction', :as => :myaction
```

This would create helper methods called `myaction_path` and `myaction_url` you can use in your controllers and views.

The Rails routing guide is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: Ah, I was missing the :as. Also, what is the difference between myaction_path and myaction_url?

Comment: `_url` generates the full url `http://www.somesite.com/some/path`. `_path` only generates the path portion `/some/path`

Answer (score 0):

```
match 'myobjs/:id/myaction' => 'myobjs#myaction', :as => :myaction
```

will create myaction_path and myaction_url as named helpers